# Normalise multiple variables to separate control values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in normalising multiple variables to the respective mean value of a control subgroup.

Say I have a data frame where I am measuring two variables (Score 1 and Score 2) from 3 different conditions (control, drug 1, drug 2).

```r
df <- data.frame(Treatment=rep(c( "Control", "Drug 1",
    "Drug 2"), each=6 ),
    Score1=c(4,5,4,5,5,6,8,9,10,8,9,9,14,15,13,15,14,15), 
    Score2=c(1,2,1,2,3,3,8,8,9,9,8,8,14,14,15,12,14,15)) 
df

   Treatment Score1 Score2
1    Control      4      1
2    Control      5      2
3    Control      4      1
4    Control      5      2
5    Control      5      3
6    Control      6      3
7     Drug 1      8      8
8     Drug 1      9      8
9     Drug 1     10      9
10    Drug 1      8      9
11    Drug 1      9      8
12    Drug 1      9      8
13    Drug 2     14     14
14    Drug 2     15     14
15    Drug 2     13     15
16    Drug 2     15     12
17    Drug 2     14     14
18    Drug 2     15     15
```

I would like to normalise each score to the mean value of the control group (for that score). The end result being:

```r
df.normal <- df
x <- mean(df$Score1[df$Treatment=="Control"])
y <- mean(df$Score2[df$Treatment=="Control"])
df.normal$Score1_normalised <- df$Score1 / x
df.normal$Score2_normalised <- df$Score2 / y
df.normal

Treatment Score1 Score2 Score1_normalised Score2_normalised
1    Control      4      1         0.8275862               0.5
2    Control      5      2         1.0344828               1.0
3    Control      4      1         0.8275862               0.5
4    Control      5      2         1.0344828               1.0
5    Control      5      3         1.0344828               1.5
6    Control      6      3         1.2413793               1.5
7     Drug 1      8      8         1.6551724               4.0
8     Drug 1      9      8         1.8620690               4.0
9     Drug 1     10      9         2.0689655               4.5
10    Drug 1      8      9         1.6551724               4.5
11    Drug 1      9      8         1.8620690               4.0
12    Drug 1      9      8         1.8620690               4.0
13    Drug 2     14     14         2.8965517               7.0
14    Drug 2     15     14         3.1034483               7.0
15    Drug 2     13     15         2.6896552               7.5
16    Drug 2     15     12         3.1034483               6.0
17    Drug 2     14     14         2.8965517               7.0
18    Drug 2     15     15         3.1034483               7.5
```

I think this is possible with dplyr but I've been struggling to get started, and as I have around 20 variables I was hoping for a shortcut rather than going about it the long way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With 20 variables do you mean 20 Scores? Would this solve the problem? `mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("Score")), funs("normalised" = . / mean(.[Treatment == "Control"])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is with aggregate() and mapply():

```
> Medias <- aggregate(df[c("Score1", "Score2")], list(df$Treatment), mean)
> Medias
  Group.1    Score1    Score2
1 Control  4.833333  2.000000
2  Drug 1  8.833333  8.333333
3  Drug 2 14.333333 14.000000
> 
> mapply( function(x, y) {x / y}, x = df[c("Score1", "Score2")], y = Medias[Medias$Group.1 == "Control" , c("Score1", "Score2")])
         Score1 Score2
 [1,] 0.8275862    0.5
 [2,] 1.0344828    1.0
 [3,] 0.8275862    0.5
 [4,] 1.0344828    1.0
 [5,] 1.0344828    1.5
 [6,] 1.2413793    1.5
 [7,] 1.6551724    4.0
 [8,] 1.8620690    4.0
 [9,] 2.0689655    4.5
[10,] 1.6551724    4.5
[11,] 1.8620690    4.0
[12,] 1.8620690    4.0
[13,] 2.8965517    7.0
[14,] 3.1034483    7.0
[15,] 2.6896552    7.5
[16,] 3.1034483    6.0
[17,] 2.8965517    7.0
[18,] 3.1034483    7.5
>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` + `tidyr` workflow. It scales well, but unfortunately becomes somewhat convoluted when you need to do some reshaping.

Using some basic `dplyr` verbs, you can get just the control values and calculate means for any column starting with `"Score"`. Since that data frame will have only one row, you can easily use those mean scores back in your normalizing of `df`.

```r
library(dplyr)

control_means <- df %>%
  filter(Treatment == "Control") %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Score")), mean)

df %>%
  mutate(Score1_norm = Score1 / control_means$Score1,
         Score2_norm = Score2 / control_means$Score2) %>%
  head()
#>   Treatment Score1 Score2 Score1_norm Score2_norm
#> 1   Control      4      1   0.8275862         0.5
#> 2   Control      5      2   1.0344828         1.0
#> 3   Control      4      1   0.8275862         0.5
#> 4   Control      5      2   1.0344828         1.0
#> 5   Control      5      3   1.0344828         1.5
#> 6   Control      6      3   1.2413793         1.5
```

However, duplicating this for more score columns will get old very quickly. Usually you can reduce duplication using `mutate_at` instead, but I don't think that would quite work because you're bringing in a different `control_means` column each time.

Instead, you could reshape both the means and the data into long shapes, then join by groups (didn't know what else you'd call them) of score 1, score 2, etc.

```r
control_means_long <- control_means %>%
  gather(key = group, value = mean_score)

control_means_long
#>    group mean_score
#> 1 Score1   4.833333
#> 2 Score2   2.000000

df %>%
  gather(key = group, value = score, starts_with("Score")) %>%
  left_join(control_means_long, by = "group") %>%
  mutate(score_norm = score / mean_score) %>%
  head()
#>   Treatment  group score mean_score score_norm
#> 1   Control Score1     4   4.833333  0.8275862
#> 2   Control Score1     5   4.833333  1.0344828
#> 3   Control Score1     4   4.833333  0.8275862
#> 4   Control Score1     5   4.833333  1.0344828
#> 5   Control Score1     5   4.833333  1.0344828
#> 6   Control Score1     6   4.833333  1.2413793
```

You probably want to drop the means column after that. If it's fine to leave it in that format, then you're done. But if you need to get back into a wide shape like you started with, you have to do a couple rounds of reshaping.

After the calculations, I'm creating a column `score_type` to show that values are as measured or as normed with `gather`. Then stick that text together with the group to make a column of `Score1_measured`, `Score1_normed`, etc. Add temporary row numbers to let `spread` match those scores properly, and put it back into wide shape.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = group, value = measured, starts_with("Score")) %>%
  left_join(control_means_long, by = "group") %>%
  mutate(normed = measured / mean_score) %>%
  select(-mean_score) %>%
  gather(key = score_type, value = value, measured, normed) %>%
  unite(group_and_type, group, score_type) %>%
  group_by(group_and_type) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key = group_and_type, value = value) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Treatment Score1_measured Score1_normed Score2_measured Score2_normed
#>   <fct>               <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 Control                 4         0.828               1           0.5
#> 2 Control                 5         1.03                2           1  
#> 3 Control                 4         0.828               1           0.5
#> 4 Control                 5         1.03                2           1  
#> 5 Control                 5         1.03                3           1.5
#> 6 Control                 6         1.24                3           1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your suggestions! I should have made clearer in my question that the variables I have named here as 'Score 1 and Score 2' actually are named a bunch of different stuff in my data set such as area, number, length etc.

What ended up working for me was a combination of dplyr and mapply. Though I appreciate the helpful dplyr tips Camille!

I obtained mean values for all variables (grouped by treatment) like so:

```html
Means<- df %>% group_by(Treatment) %>%          
    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

And then normalised each variable by its control treatment mean using mapply:

```html
normalised.df <-mapply( function(x,y) {x / y},
                             x = df[c("area", "number", "length")],
                             y = Means[Means$Treatment == "Control", c("area", "number", "length")])
```

Many thanks!